# Material Specs for Settings Layout

Tags: android

This design doesn't have material specs (TextSize, margin, padding etc) on the Official Google's Material Design Website. Does anyone know where to follow the specs from?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Padding and Margins - https://material.io/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing

Font sizes - https://material.io/guidelines/style/typography.html

Comment: How to determine the spacing between "Sound" and "Media Volume" and all other similar spaces?

Comment: Ah that appears to be defined here.
https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists.html#lists-specs

Comment: Actually, Sound is a subheader, so here https://material.io/guidelines/components/subheaders.html#subheaders-list-subheaders

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but that solves just one of the problems. The complete guide is not present anywhere.